# Embedded PHP, cannot stop?

Tags: php, html, css, embedding

I'm a little bit confused right now. I have this code:

```
<?php $this->head( ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error {
            background-color: #ccc;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
<?php ); ?>
```

I was pretty sure that you could do this. It's pretty similar to:

```
<?php if (true) { ?>
    Hei
<?php } ?>
```

In fact an error occurs:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in file.php on line 1 (line 1 of the code)

How can i better fix it?

Comment: Have you got PHP short tags enabled?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this supposed to be a conditional statement or are you trying to assign a value to $this->head?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are trying to pass the html as a variable then use heredoc.

```
$var = <<<HTML
  <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      background-color: #ccc;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
HTML;

$this->head($var);
```

You cannot do this:

```
$variable = ?> <p>omgwtfbbq</p> <?;
```

Thats just isn't a valid syntax.

Insead, you can surround it with quotes (single or double)

```
$variable = "<p>omgwtfbbq</p>";
```

Comment: @Briedis, is there some reason to avoid HEREDOC? I'm pretty sure i read somewhere that HEREDOC is evil or something... is it right or i can use it without clue?

Comment: Actually I haven't used heredoc in a real project, I just can't remember the syntax when I try to use it, instead I go for quotes :) Don't know about that being evil, but there were some drawbacks. Edit: did some digging and here are some [pros and cons](http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2008/09/08/heredoc-time-for-dead-dead-or-happy-smile-time/)

Comment: @Briedis, it didn't solved nothing. The syntax highlight of my editor still see it as string. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The main issue with HEREDOCs is how to close them.  There can be no characters before the end-of-doc characters which must be on their own line (this includes spaces).  So if your IDE does automatic tabbing, you'll get a syntax error until you remove the extra tabs.

Comment: Does your editor support HEREDOC? Many will not and code highlighting will not work properly if you use it.

Comment: There's no real reason to avoid Heredoc, it's just not used often in favor of a normal string, and as dnagirl said, the ending tag is tempermental.  It's best used exactly for this purpose, to hold larger blocks of text or HTML.

Comment: Oh, also, dnagirl didn't mention it, but in addition to there being no characters on the line before the ending tag, there must be no characters on the line after the tag as well.  A space or anything after the semicolon will kill it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a HEREDOC for the multiline text.

```
<?php
$style = <<<EOS

     <style type="text/css">
         .error {
             background-color: #ccc;
             border: 1px solid #999;
             padding: 10px;
             width: 500px;
         }
     </style>
EOS;
$this->head($style);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax with php.